# Add new HTML tag after current tag

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have a loop:

```
for tag in soup.find('article'):
```

I need to add a new tag after each tag in this loop. I tried to use the `insert()` method to no avail.

How can I solve this task with BeautifulSoup?

Comment: `for tag in soup.find('<anytag>')` will not return what you expect it to return in this instance - `soup.find('<anytag>')` returns a singular tag.  So, the `for tag` preceding the `soup.find(<anytag>)` call is essentially instructing Python to iterate over individual elements in a tag, not all the tags in the element you're targetting.

Comment: You have to look at [BeautifulSoup documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#navigablestring-and-new-tag)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use `insert_after`, and also you probably need `find_all` instead of `find` if you are trying to iterate through the node set:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup("""<article>1</article><article>2</article><article>3</article>""")

for article in soup.find_all('article'):

    # create a new tag
    new_tag = soup.new_tag("tagname")
    new_tag.append("some text here")

    # insert the new tag after the current tag
    article.insert_after(new_tag)

soup

<html>
    <body>
        <article>1</article>
        <tagname>some text here</tagname>
        <article>2</article>
        <tagname>some text here</tagname>
        <article>3</article>
        <tagname>some text here</tagname>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: insert_after  - cool! how i can add new tag after any child of article?

Comment: You probably need the append method just like how the text is added to the new tag as of above. `another_new_tag = soup.new_tag(...); article.append(another_new_tag);`